# Redirect Loop in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doin the backend of a website while learning Laravel. I have these router below:

```
Route::get('/update/survivor/flag', 'SurvivorsController@flagSurvivor');

Route::get('/submit/log/flag', 'LogsController@submitFlag');
```

And in the flagSurvivor function i have:

```
public function flagSurvivor(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'idFlagged'      =>  'required',
        'idFlagger'      =>  'required'
    ]);
    //Get the ids
    $id = $request->input('idFlagged');
    $flaggerid = $request->input('idFlagger');

    //Get the flagger name
    $survivors = Survivor::all();;
    $flaggerSurvivor = $survivors->find($flaggerid);

    //Flag a survivor
    $survivors = Survivor::all();;
    $flaggedSurvivor = $survivors->find($id);
    $flaggedSurvivor->flags = $flaggedSurvivor->flags+1;

    //Save updates
    $flaggedSurvivor->save();

    //Redirect
    return redirect('submit/log/flag')
        ->with('nameFlagged', $flaggedSurvivor->name)
        ->with('idFlagged', $id)
        ->with('nameFlagger', $flaggerSurvivor->name)
        ->with('idFlagger' , $flaggerid);
}
```

which works perfectly except for the redirect part. After inserting the change into the DB it should send data to the submitFlag function, except that it doesn't. It just keeps looping with itself until it crashes from too many redirects. The log submit page also works just fine:

```
public function submitFlag(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'nameFlagged'      =>  'required',
        'nameFlagger'      =>  'required',
        'idFlagger'        =>  'required',
        'idFlagged'        =>  'required'
    ]);
    $flaggerid = $request->input('idFlagger');
    $flaggedid = $request->input('idFlagged');
    $flaggername = $request->input('nameFlagger');
    $flaggedname = $request->input('nameFlagged');
    //Create a new log
    $flag = new Log;
    $flag->log = "The survivor $flaggername($flaggerid) reported that the survivor $flaggedname($flaggedid) is contaminated";
    //Save log
    $flag->save();
    echo "Success";
}
```

if i go to

```
localhost/submit/log/flag?idFlagger=1&idFlagged=2&nameFlagger=Matheus&nameFlagged=Tauan
```

It echoes "Success" and inserts the log into the DB. But i just don't get it why it doesn't work by sending the parameters in the flagSurvivor function. I assume I'm doing the withs in the redirects wrong, or maybe something in the routes I have no idea. Any help is appreciated!


Turns out that using

```
return redirect('submit/log/flag?nameFlagged='.$flaggedSurvivor->name.'&idFlagged='.$id.'&nameFlagger='.$flaggerSurvivor->name.'&idFlagger='.$flaggerid);
```

Instead of the 'with's that I was using works properly.

Comment: may be you should call the function rather than trying to redirect. 
I doubt the data u send through with will be taken as request in submitFlag.

So try calling submitFlag using $this->submitFlag(pass parameters) 
and modify your submitFlag function accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `redirect` to an action and the `with's` to an associative array:

```
//Redirect
return redirect()->action('LogsController@submitFlag', [
    'nameFlagged' => $flaggedSurvivor->name,
    'idFlagged' => $id,
    'nameFlagger' => $flaggerSurvivor->name,
    'idFlagger' => $flaggerid
]);
```

[Redirecting to a controller action](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions)

Comment: that indeed worked as intended. But still, from what i understood the withs should have worked. I tought that maybe they sent the variables via POST by default but i didn't find anything online about it. Got any take on that?

Comment: *Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed to change the method on the redirected request. However, most existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303 response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which kind of reaction is expected of the client.*

It's most likely going to be a GET redirection, but that ultimately depends on the server's configuration.

Comment: I never really chain `with` calls, preferring to use just a single array like illustrated, although I also thought it would work as you have it.